# Error "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element" When UI is not yet loaded

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, I use a lot of Binding with a **RelativeSource** in **FindAncestor** mode.
But WPF try to resolve those binding when the UI is not loaded yet or when elements are removed from the UI.
It cause a lot of error `Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element` in the console and a small freeze of the UI.

Is there a way to tell WPF not to try to resolve binding until elements are loaded in the visual tree?

Comment: Those error means you are mistakingly assuming that something is present in the visualtree. Use Snoop tool.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Once the visual tree is loaded, the binding is successfull. The problem is WPF try to find ancestor when the visual tree is not loaded and display a lot of fake error in the console.

Comment: That is usual behavior, and can be controlled using some debugging options. I think u can set these from `Debug>Options&Settings>Debugging>OutputWindow`.